# Kind of contractor to hire to install new basement window, where there was none before?

Tags: windows, basement, foundation, contractors

A family member is interested in getting their basement finished, and one of the things they'd like to do is have an additional bedroom in the basement.  The bedroom should have a **window.**  However, the basement doesn't have a window in the area most desired for the bedroom location.

**What kind of contractor should be hired to install a new basement window where there wasn't one before?** i.e. this is not replacing a window, but creating one where there used to be concrete, brick, etc.

The window people spoken to supply and install windows but won't do the harder parts.

It sounds like foundation-related work to me, but it's not installing or repairing foundation, rather modifying some foundation, removing bricks, installing a lintel, a window well, correct drainage?

Essentially, we're not sure where to start looking in the phone book!  Foundation people? Brick people? Other?

Comment: is the basement wall already exposed? or do you need to also dig out the opening?

Comment: It's partially exposed, but some digging for a window well would be necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start with *Architect* or *Structural Engineer* because for that kind of work you're going to need permits, which means detailed drawings for the applications.  They would probably have recommendations for a *General Contractor* that would be able to do the job (with or without subcontractors).

Answer (score 3):

What you're talking about is an egress window. We had one of those put in by a general contractor. He had to cut a notch into the concrete foundation to install the window, and move some pipes that were in the way. He knew what to do and it turned out great.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just talk to a good general contractor that is willing to take on the project. They will find the right people to do the job.

If you don't do this, then essentially you are trying to be the general contractor yourself. You can save some money that way, but if you don't know what you are doing, that savings will be an illusion.